# Python load camera settings

Tags: python, camera

I used a not mine code to generate some images, but it adds some random jitter to the camera, in the following way:

```py
  camera = bpy.data.objects['Camera']
  plane_normal = plane.data.vertices[0].normal
  cam_behind = camera.matrix_world.to_quaternion() * Vector((0, 0, -1))
  cam_left = camera.matrix_world.to_quaternion() * Vector((-1, 0, 0))
  cam_up = camera.matrix_world.to_quaternion() * Vector((0, 1, 0))
  plane_behind = (cam_behind - cam_behind.project(plane_normal)).normalized()
  plane_left = (cam_left - cam_left.project(plane_normal)).normalized()
  plane_up = cam_up.project(plane_normal).normalized()
```

And then is stored in a dictionary:

```py
  scene_struct['directions']['behind'] = tuple(plane_behind)
  scene_struct['directions']['front'] = tuple(-plane_behind)
  scene_struct['directions']['left'] = tuple(plane_left)
  scene_struct['directions']['right'] = tuple(-plane_left)
  scene_struct['directions']['above'] = tuple(plane_up)
  scene_struct['directions']['below'] = tuple(-plane_up)
```

I have those directions that look like this:

```
{'directions': {
  'above': [0, 0, 1],
  'behind': [-0.754490315914154, 0.6563112735748291, 0],
  'below': [0, 0, -1],
  'front': [0.754490315914154, -0.6563112735748291, 0],
  'left': [-0.6563112735748291, -0.7544902563095093, 0],
  'right': [0.6563112735748291, 0.7544902563095093, 0]
  }
}
```

Now, I'm trying to render images very similar to those but with little modifications. Is there a way I could load those settings to the camera so the new images are as similar as possible to the original?

P.S. Absolute novice in blender so I'm completely lost with the API and wasn't sure if this was the correct section to ask for help.

Comment: Consider using `plane_no = plane.data.polygons[0].normal` _ie_ the face normal.  Can you elaborate on steps used to generate images?

Comment: what information could be useful? This is the [code](https://github.com/sebamenabar/clevr-dataset-gen/blob/master/image_generation/render_images_restricted.py) if it is of any help

Comment: Perhaps look at `parser.add_argument('--camera_jitter', default=0.5, type=float,
    help="The magnitude of random jitter to add to the camera position")`

Comment: Yeah, I wanted to keep the random jitter, and somehow reverse engineer my directions to camera settings. I'm gonna take the easy solution of rendering new images, but also saving de .blend files so every thing will be stored. Thanks for your help anyways.